# How to divide daily/weekly/monthly value by yearly value

Tags: r, date, aggregate, summarize, tidyquant

I am trying to apply some basic math to daily stock values based on a corresponding yearly value.

## reprex

(daily prices)

```
library(tidyquant)

data(FANG)

# daily prices

FANG %>%
  select(c(date, symbol, adjusted)) %>%
  group_by(symbol)

# A tibble: 4,032 x 3
# Groups:   symbol [4]
   date       symbol adjusted
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 2013-01-02 FB         28  
 2 2013-01-03 FB         27.8
 3 2013-01-04 FB         28.8
 4 2013-01-07 FB         29.4
 5 2013-01-08 FB         29.1
 6 2013-01-09 FB         30.6
 7 2013-01-10 FB         31.3
 8 2013-01-11 FB         31.7
 9 2013-01-14 FB         31.0
10 2013-01-15 FB         30.1
# ... with 4,022 more rows
```

(max price per year)

```
FANG_yearly_high <- 
  FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  summarise_by_time(
    .date_var = date, 
    .by = "year", 
    price = AVERAGE(adjusted))

# Groups:   symbol [4]
   symbol date       price
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
 1 AMZN   2013-01-01 404. 
 2 AMZN   2014-01-01 407. 
 3 AMZN   2015-01-01 694. 
 4 AMZN   2016-01-01 844. 
 5 FB     2013-01-01  58.0
 6 FB     2014-01-01  81.4
 7 FB     2015-01-01 109. 
 8 FB     2016-01-01 133. 
 9 GOOG   2013-01-01 560. 
10 GOOG   2014-01-01 609. 
11 GOOG   2015-01-01 777. 
12 GOOG   2016-01-01 813. 
13 NFLX   2013-01-01  54.4
14 NFLX   2014-01-01  69.2
15 NFLX   2015-01-01 131. 
16 NFLX   2016-01-01 128.
```

I would like to divide each daily price by the corresponding max price for the year.

I tried:

```
  FANG %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  summarise_by_time(
    .date_var = date, 
    .by = "year", 
    price = AVERAGE(adjusted) / YEAR(date(MAX(adjusted)))
    )
```

and the get this error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x, tz = tz(x)) : 'origin' must be supplied

Any sensible way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summarise_by_time` is good if you just want to summarise. But you want to divide a daily price by a max of a period. So you need to use mutate. Below are 2 examples. The first one for daily prices, the second for weekly. You can adjust the weekly version easily to monthly.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(dplyr)

data(FANG)

# daily prices

FANG %>%
  select(c(date, symbol, adjusted)) %>%
  group_by(symbol, year = year(date)) %>% 
  mutate(price_pct = adjusted / max(adjusted))

# A tibble: 4,032 x 5
# Groups:   symbol, year [16]
   date       symbol adjusted  year price_pct
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2013-01-02 FB         28    2013     0.483
 2 2013-01-03 FB         27.8  2013     0.479
 3 2013-01-04 FB         28.8  2013     0.496
 4 2013-01-07 FB         29.4  2013     0.508
 5 2013-01-08 FB         29.1  2013     0.501
 6 2013-01-09 FB         30.6  2013     0.528
 7 2013-01-10 FB         31.3  2013     0.540
 8 2013-01-11 FB         31.7  2013     0.547
 9 2013-01-14 FB         31.0  2013     0.534
10 2013-01-15 FB         30.1  2013     0.519
# ... with 4,022 more rows
```

Weekly / monthly:

```
# weekly
FANG %>%
  select(c(date, symbol, adjusted)) %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  tq_transmute(mutate_fun = to.period,
               period = "weeks"   # change weeks to months for monthly
               ) %>% 
  group_by(symbol, year = year(date)) %>% 
  mutate(price_pct = adjusted / max(adjusted))

# A tibble: 836 x 5
# Groups:   symbol, year [16]
   symbol date       adjusted  year price_pct
   <chr>  <date>        <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 FB     2013-01-04     28.8  2013     0.519
 2 FB     2013-01-11     31.7  2013     0.572
 3 FB     2013-01-18     29.7  2013     0.535
 4 FB     2013-01-25     31.5  2013     0.569
 5 FB     2013-02-01     29.7  2013     0.536
 6 FB     2013-02-08     28.5  2013     0.515
 7 FB     2013-02-15     28.3  2013     0.511
 8 FB     2013-02-22     27.1  2013     0.489
 9 FB     2013-03-01     27.8  2013     0.501
10 FB     2013-03-08     28.0  2013     0.504
# ... with 826 more rows
```